# Is Converting to Standard Form Necessary to Check if a Proposed Solution is a Basis in Linear Programming?

Tags: linear-programming

If I have a Lp problem should I make it to standard form and then calculate number of 0s in the proposed solution and compare it to :

number of equation - number of variables;

And that's for checking wether the solution is a basis(BFS) or not.

What I know is if I have a proposed solution (expressing the original variables) I can directly check weather it is a bfs or not without the need to convert it to standard form.

P.s: this step is just the 2nd step of checking

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658146/is-converting-to-standard-form-necessary-to-check-if-a-proposed-solution-is-a-ba

Comment: @HAMDI ABDERRAHMENE, please, edit your question to clarify and elaborate more on what exactly you are looking for.  If you have a prior solution, you can feed this solution into the constraint to make sure whether it may be feasible or not. In a feasible case, you stand on a BFS.

Comment: @A.Omidi if I have a potential solution,I test if it satisfied the constraints then I calculate the number of 0s in the solutions and compare it to n of eq-n of vars, if it is less then it cannot span the space, else I go and check the determinant if !=0 then it is a BFS. my question now would make sense

Comment: @HAMDIABDERRAHMENE, what you asked is very similar to the concepts of how a linear system of equations can have a unique solution or not. BTW if in your mathematical model, there are $m$ constraints, you should have $m$ basic variables. You can read more about that in the linear-programming textbooks. Also, before setting your initial solution, first ensure that the model does not have infeasibility.

Comment: @A.Omidi For a linear programming problem with m constraints and n variables (m>n),  a basis is defined by any subset of the m  constraints that has rank n. That is, any subset of n linearly independent constraints forms a basis. so it's not necessary to add slack variables to check its validity to be a BFS?

Comment: @HAMDIABDERRAHMENE, some things should be considered. First, a linear system of equations has a *unique* solution if and only if the determinant of the matrix $\text{A}$ Not to be equal to zero. Also, a necessary and already enough condition that $Ax=b$ has the solution is to $\text{Rank(A)} = \text{Rank(A|b)}$. Now, a $m*n$ system has a unique solution based on the two mentioned points.

Comment: If $m \geq n$, in general, this system does not have any solution. Hence, if $m \leq n$ the system does have the infinite solution. (Please, be aware that there are always exceptions). BTW AFAIK, the slack variables (usually adding to the inequality system) cannot affect on the space dimension. (The space dimension referred to the non-basic variables). I hope it helps.